# Do private remote nodes save any wallet related data to disk?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli

I am considering setting up my [own](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#compiling-monero-from-source) private [remote](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/remote-node.html) node.

If I connect to that node over Tor using the [official](https://www.getmonero.org/downloads/#gui) GUI wallet running on Tails, is any wallet related data saved to disk on the server hosting the node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Do private remote nodes save any wallet related data to disk?

No. The only "related" data is the blockchain.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! So contrary to Bitcoin (in the context of Electrum), Monero doesn't require an equivalent to [electrs](https://github.com/romanz/electrs)?

Comment: Bitcoin doesn't require Electrum so I'm not sure what you're getting at. In any case, with Monero, the daemon (node) and wallet are two completely separate apps, each with their own RPC interfaces. Furthermore, Monero also has a so called light-wallet server, as used by MyMonero, which is an alternative wallet RPC, more akin to Electrum.